# Import cv2.pyd in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv3.1

I cannot find `cv2.pyd` in

```
opencv\mybuild\lib\Release
```

I use `vs2015`, `opencv3.10`, `cmake3.4.3(32bit)` and `Anaconda(32bit)` to compile `opencv3.10`.

In `vs2015` two items have failed. How can I to check which items failed and how can I find `cv2.pyd`.

I need to find it so I cant import `cv2` in `anaconda`.

Comment: Do you NEED to build it for some special reason or just instal the prebuilt?  conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0

Comment: I want to use SIFT and SURF, so I must complile again.